# DISTINCT return same ID two times wrongly

Tags: sql, distinct

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ItemId), TCode, PartNumber,ModelNumber, ItemUOM 
FROM #Results
```

This query returns:

```
ItemId   TCode   Source  PartNumber   ModelNumber   ItemUOM
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1024     1000    NULL    NULL         EA
1024     1000    FLEX    FLEX         EA
```

`#Result` is a temp table I have used left join in that query

Why does `SELECT DISTINCT` return the same `ItemID 1024` twice?

```
SELECT DISTCINT(I.ItemId),
    (DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY I.ItemId ASC)) AS RowNumber,
    (I.TCode), E.Name AS Source, 
    I.GoldenRecordNumber AS GoldenRecordNo, I.ItemCode AS MMRefNo, 
    I.ShortDescription AS ShortText, I.LongDescription AS POText, 
    Suppliers.Description AS Manufacturer, Suppliers.Name AS  ManufacturerCode, 
    Suppliers.Abbreviation AS ManufacturerAbbr, 
    ItemSuppliers.ReferenceNo AS PartNumber, ItemSuppliers.ReferenceNo AS ModelNumber, 
    UOM.Name AS ItemUOM, MG.Name AS PSGC, 
    NM.Noun AS ClassName, NM.LongAbbrevation AS ClassDescription  
INTO 
    #Results  
FROM
    Items I  
LEFT JOIN 
    ItemSuppliers ON I.ItemId = ItemSuppliers.ItemsId 
LEFT JOIN 
    Suppliers ON ItemSuppliers.ManufacturerId = Suppliers.SupplierId 
LEFT JOIN
    UnitOfMeasurement UOM ON UOM.UOMId = I.UOMId 
LEFT JOIN
    MaterialGroup MG ON MG.MaterialGroupId = I.MaterialGroupId 
LEFT JOIN 
    NounModifiers NM ON NM.NounModifierId = I.NounModifierId 
LEFT JOIN
    AutoClass AC ON AC.ClassName = NM.Noun 
LEFT JOIN
    ERP E ON E.ERPId = I.ERPName 
LEFT JOIN 
    NounModifierAttributes NMA ON NMA.NounModifierId = 
NM.NounModifierId 
LEFT JOIN
    Attributes A ON A.AttributeId = NMA.AttributeId 
LEFT JOIN
    ItemAttributes IA ON IA.ItemId = I.ItemId  
WHERE
    (I.ItemCode LIKE '%'+'2001010088'+'%' )  

SELECT 'Int' = COUNT(distinct(ItemId))  
FROM #Results
WHERE (TCode IS NOT NULL OR MMRefNo IS NOT NULL) 

SELECT DISTINCT(ItemId), 
    TCode, Source, GoldenRecordNo, MMRefNo, ShortText, POText,
    Manufacturer, ManufacturerCode, ManufacturerAbbr, PartNumber, ModelNumber, 
    ItemUOM, PSGC, ClassName, ClassDescription 
FROM 
    #Results  
WHERE 
    (TCode IS NOT NULL OR MMRefNo IS NOT NULL) 
    AND RowNumber BETWEEN (1-1)*100 + 1 AND (((1-1) * 100 + 1) + 100) - 1   

DROP TABLE #Results
```

Comment: I have added  full my sql store procedure above

Comment: `distinct` is **NOT**  a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Putting parentheses around one column after the `distinct` won't change anything

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `DISTINCT` works as expected. For instance, you could use `GROUP BY` clause to group them by *ItemId,  TCode* to get top most records

```
SELECT 
       ItemId, TCode, 
       MAX(PartNumber) PartNumber, MAX(ModelNumber) ModelNumber, 
       MAX(ItemUOM), ...
FROM #Results  
GROUP BY ItemId, TCode
```

In case any failure in *GROUP BY*  clause use `ranking` function to assign the rank and get the record based on rank value.

Answer (score 0):

if you are convinced the rows which are selected can be grouped together then it should work fine.
1. but if rows are having different data then distinct will not help.
2. use ltrim,rtrim to remove leading and trailing spaces.

example: `distinct(ltrim(rtrim(ItemId)))`

this will help if it due to spaces or for junk values